# CSS drop down menu 2nd level inline-block view

Tags: html, css

I guess the answer is simple, but still, I cannot figure out how to make my second level menu viewed as an inline-block - from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

So what I need is an inline block-listing + text aligned to the center.
Thank you very much for your help.

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Cozy Couch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Great Table</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Small Chair</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shiny Shelf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Invisible Nothing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Right Here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Somewhere Else</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
    ul {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
    ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #1e7c9a;
    margin-left:1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { 
    background: #BBBBBB;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { 
    background: #3b3b3b; 
}
li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this to your css

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
li:hover ul {
    display: block; 
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
} 
li:hover li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uavsy/1/)